# Cauchy-Davenport theorem and its extension

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, abelian-groups, additive-combinatorics

According to Cauchy-Davenport Theorem, if $A,B$ are subsets of a prime field ($F_p$) then we have the following bound on the number of elements within the sumset $A + B = \left\{ {\left. {a + b} \right|a \in A,b \in B} \right\}$:

$$\min \left( {p,\left| A \right| + \left| B \right| - 1} \right) \le \left| {A + B} \right|$$

(There is also an extension of this this theorem, by Károlyi, see here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133408/karolyis-theorem-for-finite-groups-and-its-extensions)

My questions are:

1. Can we say something **on average** about the number of elements within the sumset $A+B$? that is, what is the probability that $\left| {A + B} \right|=1,2,...,p$? can it be extended to more than two subsets?
2. In addition to the previous question, can we say that the expectation of the number of the elements is larger/smaller than the expectation when assuming that the $\left| A \right| \cdot \left| B \right|$ sums within the sumset are drawn at uniform? according to some simulations I did it appears to be larger.

Comment: I can't say anything useful, but I am a bit curious. Could you add details about your simulation as an answer? What was the comparison: you pick a random subset $A$ of size $m$, a random subset $B$ of size $n$, and compare $A+B$ to randomly drawing $mn$ elements?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Exactly. It appears that the sumset $A+B$ tends to be more "spread" than drawing $mn$ elements at random and assigning them at random to $p$ possible element (in fact you have to take into account that there are at least $\min(p,|A|+|B|−1)$ elements within the sumset). I think that it can be explained somehow by the structure of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a useful answer, just too long to fit into a comment. I was playing a bit with this, and observed the following.

Let us fix $m=|A|$, $n=|B|$ and $p$. Let us fix an element $x\in G=\Bbb{Z}_p$. We calculate the probabilities of $x$ being included in the subsets resulting from the two processes.

**Process 1:** We draw randomly, with repetition $mn$ elements from $G$. A single attempt will fail to give us $x$ with probability $1-1/p$. Thus the probability that we get $x$ in $mn$ trials is
$$
P_1(m,n,p)=1-\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{mn}.
$$

**Process 2:** We select a random subset $A\subset G$ with $m$ elements and another random subset $B\subset G$ with $n$ elements. We record whether $x\in A+B$ or not. Here $x\in A+B$ if and only if the sets $A$ and $x-B=\{x-b\mid b\in B\}$ intersect non-trivially. The set $x-B$ is also a random subset of $G$ with $n$ distinct elements. So we fail to include $x$ in $A+B$, if and only if the elements of $x-B$ were all drawn from the complement of $A$. That complement has $p-m$ elements, so we have ${p-m\choose n}$ ways of drawing the elements of $B$ from the complement. Thus
$$
P_2(m,n,p)=1-\frac{p-m\choose n}{p\choose n}=1-\frac{(p-m)(p-m-1)\cdots(p-m-n+1)}{p(p-1)(p-2)\cdots (p-n+1)}
$$
is the probability of including $x$ in process 2.

A partial explanation to your observations may be that it is always this the case that 
$$P_2(m,n,p)\ge P_1(m,n,p).$$

This follows from Bernoulli's inequality:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(1-\frac1p\right)^{mn}&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac1p\right)^m\\
&>\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac1{p-j}\right)^m\\
&>\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{m}{p-j}\right)=
\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{p-m-j}{p-j}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
This does not answer your question, because while the probabilities for various elements $x$ being included in process 1 are independent from each other, there is a built-in dependence in process 2. I cannot quantify how this will affect the expected sizes of the two resulting sets.

How pronounced were the differences that you observed? To what extent can you explain them with this?

Comment: Many thanks for your useful observation (I noted your answer somewhat late). As I see it, you didn't take into account the structure of $G$ in process 2. I think that even though there is a dependency between the $x$'s in P2, the expectation of the number of $x$'s is higher in the case of P2, due to the linearity of the expectation.
Regarding your question, I calculated numerically the expectation of the size of $A+B$ and compared it to the expectation of P1 (which is simply $mn \cdot P1(m,n,p)$). I saw that the expectation of P1 was always smaller than the numeric expectation of $|A+B|$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, Rob. This doesn't really take into account the group structure that creates dependencies. Anyway, it does point into the same direction. I just wonder, whether it is possible to calculate some more useful statistical figures about the size of $|A+B|$ in process #2 exactly?

Comment: I think that it is possible, since the probability for an intersection of size $0,1,...,min(m,n)$ between two arbitrary sets of sizes $m,n$ (taken from $G$) can be calculated.